# Roman to Integer

Tags: python, programming-challenge, interview-questions, roman-numerals

I'm trying to get better as a programmer and would love any feedback on my code. Especially the section in the while loop. How could I make this more readable? What would your opinion as an interviewer be of my code? I utilized python 2.7.

**Challenge:**

> Given a Roman Numeral, convert it to an integer.

**Example:**

> Input: "LVIII"
>     Output: 58

Here is my Code:

```
def romanToInt(self, roman):
    if not (roman):
        return 0

    LetterToValue = {'I' : 1, 
                 'V' : 5,
                 'X' : 10,
                 'L' : 50,
                 'C' : 100,
                 'D' : 500,
                 'M' : 1000}

    RomanCharacterized = list(roman)
    End = len(RomanCharacterized)
    if (End == 1):
        return LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[0]]

    start = 0
    next = start + 1
    result = 0


    while(next < End): 
                           #Value @ Start        <         Value @ Immediately Following 
        if(LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]] < LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[next]]):
            result = result + (LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[next]] - LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]])
                          #Value @ Start        ==         Value @ Immediately Following 
        if(LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]] == LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[next]]):
            result = result + (LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]] + LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[next]])
                          #Value @ Start        >         Value @ Immediately Following 
        if(LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]] > LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[next]]):
            result = result + LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]]
            start = next #Needs to advance one slot
            next = next + 1
        else:
            start = next + 1 #advances two slots
            next = start + 1


    if (start == (End -1)):
        result = result + LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[start]]

    return result
```

Comment: This function accepts invalid roman number literals like `LL`. Is this intended?

Comment: These are many Roman Numeral 'standards', which one(s) are you trying to support?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Packaging and style

Why does this function accept `self` as the first parameter?  You never use it anywhere, and it doesn't look like this function should be a method in a class.

Stick to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions (`roman_to_int()`, `LETTER_TO_VALUE`, `end`, etc.)

Avoid superfluous punctuation.  None of these expressions should be written with parentheses: `not (roman)`, `if (End == 1)`, `while(next < End)`.

A docstring with [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) would be a good idea.

### Algorithm

I see a lot of minor unnecessary complications that together make the solution more cumbersome than necessary.

There is no need to convert `roman` into the list `RomanCharacterized`: you can index directly into strings, and you can call `len()` on strings.

There is no need for the `if (End == 1)` special case: the general case for the algorithm handles one-character inputs just fine.

I see `LetterToValue[RomanCharacterized[…]]` written everywhere!  Why not convert the letters to numbers early on to avoid that verbosity?  (See `values` in my solution below.)

`start` is not a good variable name, since it is incremented in the loop (in contrast to `End`, which stays fixed).  Note that `next` is always `start + 1`, so there is an opportunity to either write `assert next == start + 1` or to eliminate one of the variables.

Going further, if you are always considering neighbouring elements of a sequence, it may be better to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) in some way.  Also, the loop logic would be much simpler if you never advance by two positions.  As long as the input is legal (i.e. not like `IIX`), you can get the same results using the function below, which I consider to be more Pythonically expressive.

```
def roman_to_int(roman):
    """
    Given a valid Roman numeral, convert it to an integer.  (Results
    for invalid inputs are undefined; no validation is performed.)

    >>> roman_to_int('LVIII')
    58
    >>> roman_to_int('C')
    100
    >>> roman_to_int('')
    0
    """
    values = [
        {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}[c]
        for c in roman
    ]
    return sum(
        +n if n >= next else -n
        for n, next in zip(values, values[1:] + [0])
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `self` argument

The `self` argument is only required if you are writing a method belonging to a class. In this case, it's unnecessary (and unused) so you can safely delete it.

---

In Python, the recommended method for casing of names is `snake_case`, with the exception of class names, which uses `CamelCase`. So, `romanToInt` instead of `roman_to_int`, `LetterToValue` would be `letter_to_value`, and so on.

---

As hoffmale mentioned in a [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198179/roman-to-integer#comment382145_198179), your code accepts invalid Roman numbers, such as `LL`, `DD`, and `IIV`:

```
print roman_to_int('LL') # 100
print roman_to_int('DD') # 1000
print roman_to_int('IIV') # 7
```

Before transforming the symbols to numbers, I would recommend to check to make sure that it is a valid Roman numeral, and perhaps `raise ValueError('Invalid Roman numeral')` if it is not, or something along those lines.